# Android Service is not running in ASUS Mobile

Tags: android, service, asus

[image]I am working on a App which is working by a background service. Service in running on all other device but not running on ASUS Z008D. I even disable ASUS Mobile Manager but it did not work.

Device Company: ASUS Mobile
Device Model: ASUS Z008D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Asus there is a pre-installed app called Asus Mobile Manager. An option in that app "auto start manager" will prevent apps from running in background. You have to give permission to your app for running in background from there.

Comment: When open that app. I see many app was enable to auto start but my App is disable. Only my app when installed is disable auto start. How to config or fix to enable default. I used Jobschedule and Jobservice to run service in background.

Answer (score 1):

check if "Background process limit" isn't selected on "No background processes"

Developer options -> Apps -> Background process limit

change to "Standard limit"